# PL/SQL: Cannot cast table%ROWTYPE to user-defined TYPE TABLE. But no error given

Tags: oracle, plsql, casting, cursor, user-defined-types

I have a **Package** with a **user-type `RECORD`** AND a **user-type `TABLE`** of the first type:

```
TYPE ObjData IS RECORD (
    Test date NOT NULL := DATE '0001-01-01',
    Val decimal
);
TYPE ObjDataCollection IS TABLE
    OF ObjData;
```

I need to call a `PROCEDURE` from the Package passing as param a `ObjDataCollection` object, fetched from a DBTable:

```
SELECT LogDate, TypeVal FROM UserLogs
```

When I call the query, it returns dozens of records, but nothing is returned by this function I tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestData RETURN MyPackage.ObjDataCollection AS
  res MyPackage.ObjDataCollection;
BEGIN
  SELECT LogDate, TypeVal
    BULK COLLECT INTO res
    FROM UserLogs
    ORDER BY LogDate;
  RETURN res;
END TestData;
```

This is Running window Log:

```
Connecting to the database MYDB.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database MYDB.
```

And this is the Output Variables window (it's empty):
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: After you open a cursor, and before the first `fetch`, `%rowcount` attributes is zero. So your `IF` condition is always false.

Comment: Yeah try giving `else` condition in the function. U will come to know if it is going there

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?  It now looks like the problem is that your unknown GUI isn't displaying the data you expect.  Or the table doesn't actually have the data you think it does.

Comment: I use Oracle SQL Developer. When I run the standalone query, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%ROWCOUNT` attribute of a cursor tells you how many rows have been fetched so far not how many rows could be fetched.  So checking the `%ROWCOUNT` before fetching data is a mistake.  That will always return 0.

In this case, your `IF` statement is unnecessary.  I also wouldn't bother to define a cursor variable either, just

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestData
  RETURN MyPackage.ObjDataCollection
AS
  res MyPackage.ObjDataCollection;
BEGIN
  SELECT LogDate, TypeVal
    BULK COLLECT INTO res
    FROM UserLogs
   ORDER BY LogDate;

  RETURN res;
END;
```

Comment: @kpull1 - Define "not working".  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  My crystal ball is in the shop at the moment.

Comment: I provided more information in the question (empty output, no error log)

Comment: So ashamed I have to recognize that was my GUI that isn't able to display user-defined types as result.